# Date extraction using regex in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a Pandas series with many text entries and I am trying to extract all the dates and sort them. The dates are written in many different formats, so the challenge is getting them all and sorting them correctly. I've been able to use 'str.findall' to successfully make a list of all dates, but it doesn't split the dates into month, day and year, so I can't really sort them. I've then tried using 'str.extractall', but it is not working how I expected.

Example with dates of type mm/dd/yyyy, mm/yyyy and so on:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(['1/1994 Primary Care Doctor:\n', 'sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Services: None\n', 'Reports MRI of brain done 12/2004 at Gravette Medical Center was WNLPrior EEG:\n'])

wfind = df.str.findall(r'\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}?[/-]?\d{2,4}')
wextract = df.str.extractall(r'(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})?[/-]?(\d{2,4})')
```

With `extract` it splits the year into two. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

The output I am hoping for is a `DataFrame` with one column containing months, another containing day and a third containing year. Expecting `NaN` to be in the column containing day and month in case there are neither.

Comment: What is the output you *do* want?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, I've added expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to extract dates that look like this: the first number is a *month*, then comes a *day*, and then a *year* that starts with `1` or `2`, then contains any digit and then can optionally be followed with two digits.

You can use

```py
df.str.extract(r'\b(?:(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/-])?(?:(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[/-])?((?:[12]\d)?\d{2})\b', expand=False)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rgKORl/2).

*More details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[/-])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])`  - Group 1: an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit, or `1` or `2` and any digit, or a `3` and then either `0` or `1`
  - `[/-]` - a `/` or `-`
- `(?:(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/-])?`  - an optional sequence of

  - `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - Group 2: an optional `0` and then a non-zero digit, or `1` and then either `0`, `1` or `2`
  - `[/-]` - a `/` or `-`
- `((?:[12]\d)?\d{2})` - Group 3: an optional sequence of `1` or `2`, then any one digit and then two digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Pandas code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['1/1994 Primary Care Doctor:\n', 'sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Services: None\n', 'Reports MRI of brain done 12/2004 at Gravette Medical Center was WNLPrior EEG:\n']})
df[['month','day','year']] = df['text'].str.extract(r'\b(?:(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[/-])?(?:(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[/-])?((?:[12]\d)?\d{2})\b', expand=False)
df
                                                text month  day  year
0                      1/1994 Primary Care Doctor:\n     1  NaN  1994
1  sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Servic...     7    8    71
2  Reports MRI of brain done 12/2004 at Gravette ...    12  NaN  2004
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series([
    '1/1994 Primary Care Doctor:\n',
    'sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Services: None\n',
    'Reports MRI of brain done 12/2004 at Gravette Medical Center was WNLPrior EEG:\n'
])

pattern = r'(?P<month>\d{1,2})[/-]?(?P<day>\d{1,2})?[/-]?(?P<year>\d{2,4})'

matches = df.str.extractall(pattern)

matches['date'] = matches['month'] + '/' + matches['day'].fillna('') + '/' + matches['year']

current_year = pd.to_datetime('today').year
matches['year'] = matches['year'].apply(lambda x: int(x) + 1900 if int(x) < current_year - 2000 else int(x) + 2000)

matches['date'] = pd.to_datetime(matches['date'], errors='coerce')

sorted_matches = matches.sort_values(by='date')
print(sorted_matches)
```

Output:

```
        month day  year       date
  match
0 0         1  19  2094 1994-01-19
2 0        12  20  1904 2004-12-20
1 0         7   8  2071 2071-07-08
```

Comment: The dates do not seem to be correct though, first line splits 1994 into day 19 and year 94, with date being 1994-01-19, but it is just 1994-01

The second splits year into two again.

The third interprets 7/8/71 as being year 2071 instead of 1971, but I could work with just the first three columns, if the other two cases were correct.

Comment: I have modify the code for you. Please have a look @JFK

Comment: I appreciate the effort. It looks to have the same issues as before, where date "1/1994" becomes day 19 and year 2094, date "12/2004" becomes day 20 and year 1904, and date "7/8/71" becomes year 2071.  What I had in mind for date 1/1994 for example was month: 1, day: NaN, year: 1994, or with date 7/8/71 month: 7, day: 8 and year: 71 (I can add the 19 later).